# How to animate the camera view in an animation?

Tags: camera

I am creating a space fleet scene. At the beginning, I want the camera to view the entire fleet. No problems. Then, once the fleet animation starts, in that the fleet is moving forward, I want the camera to circle around it 360 degrees then to zoom to the flagship which would be a carrier in the middle of the fleet. I have set Navigation preferences to "Orbit around selection", but it's not doing the orbit. I assume I need to add a circle then parent it to the circle? Or is there an easier and simpler way? Then once the 360 degrees is completed, I should be able to figure out the zooming to the flagship. Thanks Guys

Comment: you could put an empty on the ship, parent it to the ship, then parent the camera to the empty (but keep it away from it), and rotate the empty so that the camera rotate around the ship... but it won't be as flexible as creating a curve and making the camera follow the path...

Comment: OK thanks mate. I will do the curve method. Cheers